# Reputation does not subtract after migration

Tags: bug, reputation, migration

My question have reputation +5. As it migrated from askubuntu to superuser, my superuser account gain +5 reputation but does not subtracted on my askubuntu account.
So now +5 on both account with same question.
Links to the reputation tab on both accounts are:
[askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/116782/vusan?tab=reputation)
[superuser](https://superuser.com/users/310312/vusan?tab=reputation)
So isn't that the askubuntu reputation tab should show like

```
-5   migrated
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Migrations do not trigger reputation recalcs on their own - deletions do. Until the *question* actually gets deleted (which automatically occurs 30 days after the migration) then the reputation will not be lost on the source site.

Answers to migrated questions get deleted immediately upon migration, and you lose the reputation from those answers immediately as well.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you will get -5 rep soon. It likely just doesn't update your rep as soon as it's migrated.